# Php replace string with regex

Tags: php, regex

I want replace in my file all tags "<_tag_>" with "". 

I've tried this solutions:

1. `$_text = preg_replace('<\_\s*\w.*?\_>', '', $_text);`
   But I replace "<_tag_>" with "<>"
2. `$_text = preg_replace('<\_(.*?)\_>', '', $_text);`
   But I replace "<_tag_>" with "<>"

How can I also select angle brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be

```
<_.+?_>
# <_, anything lazily afterwards, followed by _>
```

In `PHP`:

```
$string = preg_replace('~<_.+?_>~', '', $string);
```

As in

```
<?php
$string = "some <_tag_> here";
$string = preg_replace('~<_.+?_>~', '', $string);
echo $string;
# some  here
?>
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/Zvnc4N).